# Why is Excel showing 'c' as the arg separator for fomulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, arguments

In Excel 2007, I have a cell with

> "=if(true,1,0)"

as the contents.  If I hit the *ENTER* key
 I get an error dialog which says, "The formula you typed contains an error."

The flyover help for that cell is shown as

> "IF(logical_testc [value_if_true]c [value_if_false])"

. I've checked the language setting for Windows and my separator is still a comma. I also checked on the auto-correction setting of Excel which was blank for ','; I even set ',' to be replaced with ',' to no avail.

If I enter the formula as

> "=if(truec 1 c 0 )"

I get the same error dialog. BUT if I try

> "=if(true c 1 c 0 )"

it works but when I edit the cell it gets changed back to

> "=IF(TRUEc 1c 0 )"

So, why does Excel now think that arguments for formula need to be separated with 'c' instead of ','?

If it matters, this install was an upgrade from Office 2003 but I didn't notice this bug after the upgrade over two years ago.

[Note: I found this issue with a large formula involving Match() and Index() but it shows up with any formula so I've used a simple example above]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://digilander.libero.it/foxes/Excel/Excel_How_to_change_the_argument_separator.htm) Excel uses the **List separator** defined in the Windows localization settings.

To change it, open the **Region and Language** control panel and click **Additional settings...**.
[image]

Now change the **List separator** back to `,` and it should be fixed.
[image]